# Rake Task in a Rails engine 4.2 failing rapidfire gem warning: already initialized constant STATS_DIRECTORIES

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines, rapidfire-gem

using ruby 2.1.1 and rails 4.2

just created a new engine

```
rails plugin new QuestionEngine  --mountable
```

modified gemfile

added

```
gem 'rapidfire', group: [:development]
```

ran

```
bundle
```

if I do `gemlist` I see

```
rake (10.4.2, 10.1.0)
ransack (1.5.1)
rapidfire (2.0.0)
```

Rapidfire has a built in rake task

I was inside the app area and not in test/dummy

```
bundle exec rake rapidfire:install:migrations


gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/tasks/statistics.rake:4: warning: already initialized constant STATS_DIRECTORIES
gems/ruby-2.1.1@kloudreadiness/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/tasks/statistics.rake:4: warning: previous definition of STATS_DIRECTORIES was here
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'rapidfire:install:migrations'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am trying to use this gem within the engine but the migration is failing. Previously I tried the gem on another application and it ran fine.

I am not that familiar with rails engines I also tried

```
bin/rails bundle exec rake rapidfire:install:migrations
```

I deleted the engine, renamed it lowercase and moved it outside of another directory and tried again but it didn't work. I have rake installed.

**Also I would like to add that rapidfire itself is an engine so what I am doing is mounting an engine within an engine.**

Answer (score 2):

Test/dummy is a dummy application inside the engine I generated. You are supposed to do rails s inside test/dummy to test your engine.

A rails engine needs a dummy app to be mounted on. Rapidfire is such an engine.

I have figured out that the rapidfire given installations instructions works inside test/dummy only. I don't think you can mount an engine on an engine.

You should be mounting the rapidfire engine on your test/dummy app inside your engine and not the engine that you created.

I want to add that this doesn't end up mounting rapidfire on the engine at all. Mounting the engine on a dummy test environment inside the engine won't work because eventually when I mount the engine itself on the app that I am building then the rapidfire features won't work because it was actually mounted on the dummy app and not on the engine itself...

However this question is asking how to run installation files from the rapidfire gem inside an engine.

Comment: And everybody who visits your question and reads this answer understands what they need to do to fix it?

Comment: There you go, let the voting begin. I hope it survives the low quality queue with this edit.